# Why won't my hibiscus bushes flower?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I bought a hibiscus start from the Island and planted it. It grew to full bush size days ago, but there are still no flowers. It's summer so I figured it would flower just like the island.

Are there conditions to making the bush flower?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wait - each bush blooms at a different time of year, for a specific span of days. According to [this wiki](http://acnewleaf.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Hibiscus#Red_Hibiscus), the hibiscus plants all flower from June 28 to July 5th, and flower from July 6th to September 15th.

In just a few more days, you should start to see them flower.

For reference, [this image](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Bush?file=Chartbush.jpg) shows the different stages of each bush:

[image]